# MultiMerch Marketplace не отправляет письма о Поступившем Заказе Продавцу

Tags: opencart

Кто в курсе,какая версия MultiMerch Marketplace отправляет письма о Поступления Заказа,не админу сайта,а продавцу.Может есть Решения как сделать шоб письма об новом заказе ,поступали не админу сайта а продавцу.

Answer (score 1):

Любая из 7.х и 8.х отправляет и админу, и продавцам. В старых версиях отправляли письма продавцам только в статусе Completed, современные отправляют всегда.